# How to get the displayed image frame from UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I modify the UIImageView's contentMode property. So my image's frame is not equal to the frame of UIImageView. My problem is how to retrive the image's frame from UIImageView.

As the following example, the orange rectangle is the UIImageView's border. It is obviously that the frame of image is not the same as UIImageView.

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If it's `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, it's something like this:

```
UIImageView *iv; // your image view
CGSize imageSize = iv.image.size;
CGFloat imageScale = fminf(CGRectGetWidth(iv.bounds)/imageSize.width, CGRectGetHeight(iv.bounds)/imageSize.height);
CGSize scaledImageSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width*imageScale, imageSize.height*imageScale);
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(roundf(0.5f*(CGRectGetWidth(iv.bounds)-scaledImageSize.width)), roundf(0.5f*(CGRectGetHeight(iv.bounds)-scaledImageSize.height)), roundf(scaledImageSize.width), roundf(scaledImageSize.height));
```

Comment: So, UIImageView has no direct method to retrieve the frame of image. It needs to be calculated manually, right?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it doesn't even seem to have a private method that returns the frame of the image based on `contentMode`. I guess the calculations are performed in `-drawRect:` and `-sizeThatFits:`.

Comment: I tried sizeThatFits:, it cannot retrieve the frame of image. I changed the implementation about UIImageView. If I have to calculate the imageFrame by self, I will prefer the contentMode UIViewContentModeScaleToFill.

Comment: This works, but you should remove the `floorf` functions from `CGRectMake`. They aren't necessary (CGrect takes CGFloats) and it's best to let iOS handle the rounding. My sizes were occasionally off by a pixel until I removed `floorf`.

Comment: My sizes were occasionally off by a pixel until I added `floorf` to the image frame sizes also. So the last line should be (for me at least):

`CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(floorf(0.5f*(CGRectGetWidth(iv.bounds)-scaledImageSize.width)), floorf(0.5f*(CGRectGetHeight(iv.bounds)-scaledImageSize.height)), floorf(scaledImageSize.width), floorf(scaledImageSize.height));`

Comment: @AlexeyGolikov Thanks, I corrected the code. I also think that `roundf()` _should be_ more appropriate than `floorf()`, but I'm not sure, to be honest.

Comment: you can use this code in swift with round() fmin() functions

Comment: Zooming imageview in UIScrollView chnages the frame.

Comment: How do you process when it's not UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit ?

Comment: import AVKit
    
let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: containerView.bounds);

Answer (score 32):

In fact, it's built-in since iOS 4 (for `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`):

```
@import AVFoundation;

AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imageView.image.size, imageView.bounds);
```

Since frame components may be not round numbers, consider wrapping the call by

```
CGRectIntegral(…)
```

See http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/ for more tricks.

Comment: Instead of ``imageView.bound`` i had to pass ``imageView.frame``

Answer (score 12):

Use this api from AVFoundation

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

CGRect imageRect = 
    AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imageView.image.size, imageView.bounds);
```

Answer (score 6):

**Its very easy now**

```
import AVKit
    
let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: containerView.bounds);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 if you want to calculate it yourself, use below code written by me.

func getImageFrameInImageView(imageView : UIImageView) -> CGRect {
    /*
    by 徐明刚， ericxu1983@163.com
    算法：
        设高宽比 r = h/w, 则：r(imageView) 缩写成r(v), r(image)缩写为r(i), 
        if r(i) > r(v), 则
        h(i) = h(v), 
        h(i) / w(i) = r(i) -> w(i) = h(i) / r(i)
        y = 0
        x = (w(v) / 2)  - (w(i) / 2)
    反之
    */

    let image = imageView.image!
    let wi = image.size.width
    let hi = image.size.height
    print("wi:\(wi), hi:\(hi)")

    let wv = imageView.frame.width
    let hv = imageView.frame.height
    print("wv:\(wv), hv:\(hv)")

    let ri = hi / wi
    let rv = hv / wv
    print("ri:\(ri), rv:\(rv)")

    var x, y, w, h: CGFloat

    if ri > rv {
        h = hv
        w = h / ri
        x = (wv / 2) - (w / 2)
        y = 0
    } else {
        w = wv
        h = w * ri
        x = 0
        y = (hv / 2) - (h / 2)
    }

    return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
}
```

To test if the function is right or not, I've used another view identifying the border of the image in UIImageView.

```
    let frameIdentifyBorderView = UIView(frame: imageFrameInImageView)
    frameIdentifyBorderView.layer.borderWidth = 3
    frameIdentifyBorderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

    imageView.addSubview(frameIdentifyBorderView)
```

[image]

perfect!

Comment: Super, I appreciate. And it is even better as a imageFrame property in extension of UIImageView.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use [AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerectwithaspectratioinsider).  Just import AVFoundation and you can get the rect in a single line of Code. Swift 4.  Be sure to import AVFoundation.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageView = UIImageView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        imageView.frame = self.view.bounds
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?w=940&h=650&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb")!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dt = data else{print("error");return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let image = UIImage(data: dt) else{print("error");return}
                self.imageView.image = image
                self.imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
                let realImageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: self.imageView.bounds)


                //proof
                let view = UIView(frame: realImageRect)
                view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                view.layer.borderWidth = 3
                self.view.addSubview(view)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `let realImageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: self.imageView.frame)`. `bounds` returns size without x and y relative to superview.