# Fit UIImageView to image content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Is it possible to fit perfectly an `UIImageView` to its content, so that:

- the origins of the image and the `UIImageView` object coincide;
- the frame of the image and the `UIImageView` object coincide?

I tried using the following code:

```
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(self.imageView.bounds.origin.x,
                                     self.imageView.bounds.origin.y,
                                     self.imageView.bounds.origin.x + self.imageView.image.size.width,
                                     self.imageView.bounds.origin.y + self.imageView.image.size.height)];
```

However, in this way the `UIImageView` object starts at `(0,0)`, while the image is centered on the screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is [a possible answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711615/how-to-get-the-displayed-image-frame-from-uiimageview) linked in another question.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is something along the lines of:

```
   [self.imageView setFrame: AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(imageSize, self.imageView.frame)];
```

Where *imageSize* is the aspect ratio you wish to maintain, and the in this case *self.imageView.frame* is the bounding rect.

This is part of the AVFoundation Framework so make sure to include:

```
  #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seem you want UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

**UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit** - will fit the image inside the image view. If the image is smaller than the image view it will be centered.

**UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill** - will fill the image inside the image view. If the image is smaller/bigger than the image view it will be scaled.

Apple Documentation for [UIViewContentMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentMode)

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to fit perfectly an UIImageView to its content?" Yes. Your code attempts to set the `bounds` of the `UIImageView`. What it *sounds* like you want to do, is set the `frame` of the `UIImageView` to the size of the image.

Do a bit of Googling if you are unfamiliar with the difference between the `frame` of a `UIView` and the `bounds` of a `UIView`; it is an important distinction. If you want to set the actual size or location of the `UIImageView`, use its `frame`, which operates in the coordinate space of the `UIView` that contains your `UIImageView`. If instead you wanted to affect the coordinate space of views contained by your `UIImageView`, you would use the `bounds`.

Comment: I did change my view frame as you are suggesting; however, as soon as the movement begins, the frame is resized and does not correspond to the image frame anymore.

Comment: It sounds like the code you are using to move the `UIImageView` is changing the `width` and `height` of the `frame`, which should not be necessary. Update your question to include the code that is moving the `UIImageView`.