# Adding gesture recognizer to UIImage, not UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` whose 'View Mode' is set to 'Aspect Fit' in Interface Builder.I want to add gesture recognizer to only my image inside of the `UIImageView`.To clarify what i say:

I have a `UIImageView` whose `bounds.size.width = 100;` and `bounds.size.height = 100;`  and I have a `UIImage` whose size is 100x50. So, when I add my `UIImage` to my `UIImageView` there exists some spaces of 25 from top and 25 from bottom. But I don't want to recognize user's tap when he/she taps on these spaces. I just want to know when user tapped on `UIImage`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `UIImage` extends from `NSObject` you can not add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it, you have to add gesture to the `UIImageView` itself. Then in any of the `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

or

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

get touch's location in `UIImageView`. Then by using `CGPoint location = [_gesture locationInView:yourImageView]` get the touched point, now get the image's frame using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711615/how-to-get-the-displayed-image-frame-from-uiimageview) link. Now check if the point is in Image's frame or not by using:

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint ( CGRect rect, CGPoint point );
```

This might help you.

Comment: This is totally what I asked.Thank you.You solved a lot for me.

Comment: I did it by using  `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the gesture recognizer to the imageView.  What you can do it use the gesture recognize delegate methods:

```
- gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:
//OR
- gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:
```

You can then figure out where the user tapped in the imageView and compute if the touch landed inside the image in the imageView or outside the image.

You can do this using using the following:

```
CGPoint tapPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:imageView];
// use tap point to compute if it lands inside the image.
```

Comment: Thank you, too.But in other answer all parts are covered.So I accepted the other one.The given link for how to calculate the imageView's image's frame and the CGRectContainsPoint are included in the other answer.