# Draw rectangles on image view.image not scaling properly - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect, azure-cognitive-services

1. I start out with an `imageView.image` (a photo).
2. I submit (POST) the `imageView.image` to remote service ([Microsoft face detection](https://www.projectoxford.ai/demo/face#detection)) for processing.
3. Remote service returns JSON of `CGRect`'s for each detected face on the image.
4. I feed JSON into my UIView to draw the rectangles. I initiate my UIView with a frame of `{0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height}`. <-- *my thinking, a frame equivalent to the size of the `imageView.image`*
5. Add my UIView as a subview of `self.imageView` OR `self.view` (tried both)

**End Result:**
Rectangles are drawn but they do not appear correctly on the `imageView.image`. That is, the CGRects generated for each of the faces are supposed to be relative to the image's coordinate space, as returned by the remote service but they appear off once I add my custom view.

I believe I may have a scaling issue of some sort as, if I divide each value in the CGRects / 2 (as a test) I can get an approximation but still off. The microsoft documentation states the detected faces are returned with rectangles indicating the location of faces in the image **in Pixels**. Yet, aren't they being treated as points when drawing my path?

Also, shouldn't I be initiating my view with a frame equivalent to the `imageView.image`'s frame so that the view matches an identical coordinate space as the submitted image?

Here is a screenshot example of what it looks like if i try to scale down each CGRect by dividing them by 2.

[image]

I am new to iOS and broke away from the books to work on this as a self exercise.  I can provide more code as needed. Thanks in advance for your insight!

#### EDIT 1

I add a subview for each rectangle as I iterate over an array of face attributes which include the rectangle for each face via the following method, which gets called during `(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

```
- (void)buildFaceRects {

    // build an array of CGRect dicts off of JSON returned from analized image
    NSMutableArray *array = [self analizeImage:self.imageView.image];

    // enumerate over array using block - each obj in array represents one face
   [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

       // build dictionary of rects and attributes for the face
       NSDictionary *json = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:obj[@"attributes"], @"attributes", obj[@"faceId"], @"faceId", obj[@"faceRectangle"], @"faceRectangle", nil];

       // initiate face model object with dictionary
       ZGCFace *face = [[ZGCFace alloc] initWithJSON:json];

       NSLog(@"%@", face.faceId);
       NSLog(@"%d", face.age);
       NSLog(@"%@", face.gender);
       NSLog(@"%f", face.faceRect.origin.x);
       NSLog(@"%f", face.faceRect.origin.y);
       NSLog(@"%f", face.faceRect.size.height);
       NSLog(@"%f", face.faceRect.size.width);

       // define frame for subview containing face rectangle
       CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);

       // initiate rectange subview with face info
       ZGCFaceRectView *faceRect = [[ZGCFaceRectView alloc] initWithFace:face frame:imageRect];

       // add view as subview of imageview (?)
       [self.imageView addSubview:faceRect];

   }];

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    /* Image info */
    UIImageView *iv = self.imageView;
    UIImage *img = iv.image;
    CGImageRef CGimg = img.CGImage;

    // Bitmap dimensions [pixels]
    NSUInteger imgWidth = CGImageGetWidth(CGimg);
    NSUInteger imgHeight = CGImageGetHeight(CGimg);
    NSLog(@"Image dimensions: %lux%lu", imgWidth, imgHeight);

    // Image size pixels (size * scale)
    CGSize imgSizeInPixels = CGSizeMake(img.size.width * img.scale, img.size.height * img.scale);
    NSLog(@"image size in Pixels: %fx%f", imgSizeInPixels.width, imgSizeInPixels.height);

    // Image size points
    CGSize imgSizeInPoints = img.size;
    NSLog(@"image size in Points: %fx%f", imgSizeInPoints.width, imgSizeInPoints.height);



       // Calculate Image frame (within imgview) with a contentMode of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
       CGFloat imgScale = fminf(CGRectGetWidth(iv.bounds)/imgSizeInPoints.width, CGRectGetHeight(iv.bounds)/imgSizeInPoints.height);
       CGSize scaledImgSize = CGSizeMake(imgSizeInPoints.width * imgScale, imgSizeInPoints.height * imgScale);
       CGRect imgFrame = CGRectMake(roundf(0.5f*(CGRectGetWidth(iv.bounds)-scaledImgSize.width)), roundf(0.5f*(CGRectGetHeight(iv.bounds)-scaledImgSize.height)), roundf(scaledImgSize.width), roundf(scaledImgSize.height));


       // initiate rectange subview with face info
       ZGCFaceRectView *faceRect = [[ZGCFaceRectView alloc] initWithFace:face frame:imgFrame];

       // add view as subview of image view
       [iv addSubview:faceRect];

   }];
```

Comment: In which method do you add your UIView as a subview of your imageView ?

Comment: I updated the question.  I add the subviews (one per face/rectangle) as I iterate over an array of dicts

Comment: What are the dimensions of the photo vs the dimensions of the imageviewer it is being displayed in? I had the same scenario as yours for a web page - the original photo was 1920x1080, the view img was 480x270. Therefore the face dimensions returned by the FaceApi had to be scaled by 0.25 when drawing the boxes.

Comment: @AlexS the response from Poql builds down the same.  I was adding the drawn rectangle view as a subview of the wrong frame/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've got several problems :

1. Microsoft returns pixel and iOS uses points. The difference between them is just about screen dimension. For instance on an iPhone 5 : 1 pt = 2 px and on an 3GS 1px = 1 pt. Look at the iOS documentation for more informations.
2. The frame of your UIImageView is not the image frame. When Microsofts returns the frame of a face, it returns it in the frame of the image and not  in the frame of the UIImageView. So we've got  a problem of coordinates system.
3. Be careful about time if you use Autolayout. The frame of a view set by constraints is not the same when ViewDidLoad: is called than when you see it on the screen.

Solution :

I'm just a read-only Objective C developer so I can't give you code. I could in Swift but it's not necessary.

1. Convert pixels into points. That's easy : use ratio.
2. Define the frame of a face using what you did. Then you have to move the coordinates you determined from the image frame coordinates system to the UIImageView coordinates system. That's less easy. It depends on the contentMode of your UIImageView. But I quickly find informations about it on the Internet.
3. If you use AutoLayout, add the frame of the face when AutoLayout finishes to calculate the layouts. So when ViewDidLayoutSubview: is called. 
   Or, that's better, use constraints to set your frame in the UIImageView.

I hope to be clear enough.

Some links :

1. [iOS Drawing Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)
2. [Displayed Image Frame In UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711615/how-to-get-the-displayed-image-frame-from-uiimageview)

Comment: Thanks @Poql, that certainly set me in the right direction.  by determining the ImageView.image frame and using that as the frame for my custom view I was able to align my frames, however, I still can't figure out how to calculate the ratio from pixels to points.  See my second edit,  I get the same dimensions in pixels as I do in points. Shouldn't I be getting x2 pixels per point on an iPhone 6? I ended up  hardcoding a scale factor of 2 and dividing my rects by that and it is close enough but would be nice to figure out the correct way.

Comment: The document talks about a contentScaleFactor property in UIImage, UIScreen, UIView and CALayer. Dividing by it should do the work.