# Determining the frame of the image inside UIImageView

Tags: swift

I am trying to determine the frame of the image inside the UIImageView.  Below is my attempt.  I have outlined in blue the border of the image.  As can be seen, the border does not appear to match the image.  Please can someone help?

Has auto layout of the UIImageView affected the result?

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
var margin: UILayoutGuide!


 let imgViewFrame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: margin.layoutFrame.width, height: margin.layoutFrame.height)
    let imgView = UIImageView.init(frame: imgViewFrame)
    imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    view.addSubview(imgView)

    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    let image = UIImage.init(named: imageName)
    imgView.image = image
    imageView = imgView

    //Test
    let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imgView.image!.size, insideRect: self.imageView.frame)
    let imageBorderCheckView = UIView.init(frame: imageRect)
    imageBorderCheckView.layer.borderWidth = 3
    imageBorderCheckView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    view.addSubview(imageBorderCheckView)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711615/how-to-get-the-displayed-image-frame-from-uiimageview

Comment: suspect this line `let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imgView.image!.size, insideRect: self.imageView.frame)
  ` tried to print `self.imageView.frame` before it ?

Comment: can you copy the outline code to `viewDidAppear` and try

Comment: @Sh_Khan BINGO! you are correct.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using image frame here

```
let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imgView.image!.size, insideRect: self.imageView.frame)
```

is too early try it once inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` / `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
//Test
   let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imgView.image!.size, insideRect: self.imageView.frame)
   let imageBorderCheckView = UIView.init(frame: imageRect)
   imageBorderCheckView.layer.borderWidth = 3
   imageBorderCheckView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
   view.addSubview(imageBorderCheckView)
}
```