# UIImage Text Overlay - CGPoint Incorrect; Wrong Image Size?

Tags: swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to overlay text on the bottom-left corner of a UIImage.  I get the image from the device's camera roll, perform the overlay, then assign it to a UIImageView on a ViewController.  The vertical CGPoint is never correct, however, as the height of the image seems to be different than what I'm getting from view.bounds.height.  The following is what I've been working with; what change should I make to be able to get the correct CGPoint to assign the overlay label to? Thanks!

Result (should be bottom-left):

[image]

class PhotosVC: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var photoView: UIImageView!

func presentPicker() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {
        action in
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: {
        action in
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    presentPicker()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("Issue getting photo from imagePickerController")
        return }

    
    let CGPointBottomLeft = photoView.bounds.height
    print(photoView.bounds.height) // Is 336

    let imageWithText = textToImage(drawText: "Overlayed text", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGPointBottomLeft))
    self.photoView.image = imageWithText
}

 func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
     dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

func textToImage(drawText text: String, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let textColor = UIColor.white
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 212)! // Only visible if huge

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

Comment: The image size is different of the image rendered, well it's almost getting the `UIImageView` size, after layout change and contextMode (aspectFit, etc? ). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711615/how-to-get-the-displayed-image-frame-from-uiimageview

Comment: Thank you! This got me looking in the right direction.  I'll get the size after the image is set, then apply my changes a different way using that rendered size.